# constructor injection vs field injection for @Value

Tags: spring

In general Spring advocates constructor-base injection. However, does this make sense for @Value fields? The field injection for @Value is more concise and legible (at least to me), the only disadvantage is that the field can't be make final. Which doesn't seem to be worth the increased code verbosity, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely constructor injection. Have you tried to unit test the class on which you are using field injection? Was it an easy task to mock its dependencies? With constructor injection is way easier to do that, so go for it instead of field injection.